# Paginação PDF wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf, paginação

Galera não manjo muito de wordpress maaas...

Tem alguma maneira de mudar a forma de vizualizar pdf's já existente em um site ( que no caso são revistas ) que atualmente é o padrão de quando vc abre um pdf em um browser

Dei uma pesquisada e existe uns que até funciona mas você precisa criar uma page exclusiva para aquele PDF, e no caso o que tenho é uma page com varias 'revista' que ao clicar abriria o pdf view só que com paginação

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor, se possível com imagens de como está e como gostaria que estivesse

Comment: Atualmente está assim o PDF VIEW : https://puu.sh/BM80c/58863998e9.png ( padrão ) 

Estou querendo de alguma forma alterar ele para esse modo 
https://pdf-light-viewer.wp.teamlead.pw/demo/#page/6

algo como isso só que mudasse no 'link' gerado pelo pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **ISSUU**.
Pode inserir um html estático, em qualquer página, depois de cadastrar lá a sua revista e ver no seu site, com paginação, zoom, etc...

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 75%;"><div data-url="https://issuu.com/larevueautomobile/docs/la-revue-automobile-mag-14" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: absolute;" class="issuuembed"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script></div>
```

[Tutorial](https://help.issuu.com/hc/en-us/articles/213345907-Embedding-an-Issuu-Publication-on-Your-Website-or-Blog)